Prometheus query_range how to set start and end date and have one calculated and sum value of domains
I googled as much as I could to find and reach what I'm going to have, but I have some problems.
I downloaded libvirt_exporter on instance1.mysite.com to have the values of how much each VM downloads and uploads.
This is my code:
import requests
response_tmp =requests.get(
    'http://prom.mysite.com:9091/api/v1/query_range',
    params={
        'query': 'sum(increase(libvirt_domain_interface_stats_receive_bytes_total[2h]))',
        'start': '2024-10-01T00:00:00.000Z', # RFC3339, UTC
        'end':   '2024-10-13T00:00:00.000Z', # RFC3339, UTC
        'step':  '60'
        },
        auth=('admin', 'myStrongAdminPassWord')
        )#.json()['data']['result']

This is current result:
{"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"exceeded maximum resolution of 11,000 points per timeseries. Try decreasing the query resolution (?step=XX)"}

But if I change the start-end to a newer start date like 2024-10-12T00:00:00.000Z, it is something like this:
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "domain": "instance-0000017d",
          "instance": "instance1.mysite.com:9177",
          "job": "libvirt_exporter",
          "target_device": "tapc1aedd0e-fd"
        },
        "values": [
          [1728722820, "13668737203.838501"
          ],
          [1728722880, "20305044171.814877"
          ],
          [1728722940, "26668580969.595806"
          ],
          [1728723000, "33146620341.0449"
          ],
          [1728723060, "40289211402.494484"
          ],
          [1728723120, "46987842952.288124"
          ],
          [1728723180, "53823854756.43225"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

But as I understood, the increase function does this: 13668737203.838501 + 20305044171.814877 + 26668580969.595806 + 33146620341.0449 + 40289211402.494484 + 46987842952.288124 + 53823854756.43225, but I see all the values.
Would you please help me regarding this?

Initial error: you request 12 days with step 60 seconds. This is 17280 data points, which is bigger than threshold oh 11000, which Prometheus has already said to you.

Increase over two ours range means that for every data point increase will be calculated over two hours before that point. If you want increase of two hours with results every two hours change your step to 7200(=26060)

@markalex thanks, but I'm going to have only one value. How can I have it?

Not sire what you mean. If you want a single value with increase over desired range - you should use query instead of a query_range.
